# How to combine queryBuilder and raw queries on join table from many to many relation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have got following query

```sql
SELECT news.*, count(*) AS common_tags
FROM news
JOIN news_news_tag ON news.id = news_news_tag.news_id
WHERE news_tag_id IN 
   (SELECT news_tag_id FROM news_news_tag WHERE news_id = 2 ) 
AND news.id != 2 GROUP BY news.id ORDER BY common_tags DESC
```

What I want to achieve is to get hydrated news objects ordered by number of common tags with provided news id. `News` and `Tag` are many to many relation with `news_news_tag` join table.

`News` entity have got much more other relations. This is why I don't want to create a native query by myself to handle all other relations.
I would like to convert above query to use it with query builder. I wasn't able to use a DQL because my `where` statement uses a join (junction) table and I also need to use a `join` on that table.

All in all I have got 2 problems:

1. How can I create DQL subquery to select something from many to many join table)? If I know that I could do something like: `->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in('u.id', $mySubQueryAsDQL))`
2. How to add that `join` statement that I could use `news_tag_id` in `where` statement?

If it is not possible I think that I would need to create two bidirectional one-to-many and many-to-one relations instead of many-to-many and work on special joining entity.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with following solution. I decided to split that query into two separate ones. In first I can use just simple raw query as I need results only to `where` statement. Second query can be build using query builder in a normal way. 
You have to only get rid of an extra count column at the end.

However if someone knows the solution how to use my first raw query directly inside query builder as a raw subquery for where statement please share with me.

```php
public function getRelatedNews($newsId, $limit = 6)
    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $sql = 'SELECT news_tag_id FROM news_news_tag WHERE news_id = :newsId';
    try {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    } catch (DBALException $e) {
        return [];
    }
    $stmt->execute(['newsId' => $newsId]);
    $newsTagId = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if (empty($newsTagId)) {
        return [];
    }

    $newsTagId = array_column($newsTagId, 'news_tag_id');

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(n.id) as common_tags_count')
        ->innerJoin("n.tags", "t")
        ->andWhere('t.id IN(:tagsId)')->setParameter('tagsId', array_values($newsTagId))
        ->andWhere('n.id != :newsId')->setParameter('newsId', $newsId)
        ->orderBy('common_tags_count', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->groupBy('n.id')
    ;

    $results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    $news = [];
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $news[] = $result[0];
    }

    return $news;
}
```